# Cannot Assign requested Address in AWS - JAVA Server Socket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sockets, amazon-ec2, bind

I'm making a call to the `ServerSocket` constructor with the following parameters.

`ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(0, num, host);`

The values of the variable are:
`num=5 & host=/56.224.235.106`

And 56.224.235.106 is the IP adress of the machine the code resides on.

This line is causing the exception following exception:
`Error : java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address`

BTW, This is an AWS instance where I'm hosting 2 instances. I have one client and a server instance and there are 2 separate security groups for these instances where I have allowed TCP traffic from any iPV4 addresses.

How can I resolve this, is there an issue with my code or does my security group setting needs some change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you would not bind to the IP address directly.  You would instead bind to all interfaces by not specifying a `host`.  In this way you will respond to any incoming connections to the specified port.  If I look at a Wildfly server I have running with Apache HTTPD in front of it I get:

```
$ netstat -na | grep LIST
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

In my case the Wildfly server is using IPv4 and Apache is using IPv6.  But they are both listening on what is, for IPv4, `0.0.0.0`.  The O/S takes care of the external interface to internal address mapping.

If you truly only want to listen for external connections (i.e. you don't want someone on `localhost` connecting) then run the `ifconfig` command to determine what your "internal" IP is.  For me I get:

```
$ ifconfig -a
ens5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 172.30.1.191  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.30.1.255

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
```

The `172.30.1.191` address is in a private IP address range (specifically what was called a Class B private network) and is maintained by Amazon.  Listening on the IP that your machine uses will prevent connections from `localhost`.